# Can I get a marker's coordinates for a searched place as shown in google maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

**Situation**

I'm using the Google Maps Javascript API (experimental Version, 3.exp) on a website to draw a Google map using a Google Maps url. The map shows a marker that is centered for a particular location. The user has the option to change the url to another google maps url, which will draw a different map for that location.

I'm currently using the Geocoding service, but it isn't the same as searching a place on Google Maps, which is what I need.

- If zero results are returned, I'm given a default location
- If a partial match is returned, the location isn't the same as search results in google maps

So, is there a way to extract a marker's location (latlng coordinates) from a google maps url (after searching a place on google maps)? Or is there a way to request this data somehow (through an API) using a url?

I'm currently using a normal url (not a share or embed one), but any url will do.

---

### Code

```js
var url = 'https://www.google.co.kr/maps/place/%EC%84%9C%EC%9A%B8%EB%AC%B5%ED%98%84%EC%B4%88%EB%93%B1%ED%95%99%EA%B5%90/@37.6089244,127.0714647,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x357cbbb0c068042b:0xd9af658c047868cc';
maps = url.split("/");

if(typeof maps[5] == "undefined" || typeof maps[6] == "undefined") {
    console.log('incorrect google map URL');
    return false;
}

var pos = maps[6].replace("@", "").split(","),
  zoom = Number(pos[2].replace("z", "")),
  Latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(pos[0], pos[1]),
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(element), {
    center: Latlng,
    zoom: zoom,
    scrollwheel: true,
    navigationControl: true,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    scaleControl: false,
  });

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: Latlng,
  map: map,
});
```

```html
<div id="element">Google Map should be here</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is partially correct. If you search a place in google maps, then use the generated URL without panning the map, your map will offset by the correct amount (using my method to draw a map and marker to correct the adjusted lat/lng values of a place's marker in google maps). Otherwise, this solution will not work in my situation, because I'm using the lat/lng coordinates in a google maps url (which is based on the viewport's center and not the place's marker lat/lng values).

```js
      // make a new Latlng object (var Latlng = new google.maps.LatLng...)
      // make a new map (var map = new google.maps.Map...)
      // add a new marker (var marker = new google.maps.Marker...)

      // set the tile size to 256 pixels
     var TILE_SIZE = 256;

      // use a setTimeout to move the marker to the correct position after 
      // initializing your map (I tried with different values, and 300 seems 
      // to be the lowest value.
     setTimeout(function() {
       // get the new center for your map (because using a url from google 
       // maps will display your marker and map center left (west) of the
       // actual place.
       var newLatlng = getNewCenter(map, marker.getPosition(), map.getZoom());

       // set the new map center and marker
       map.setCenter(newLatlng);
       marker.setPosition(newLatlng);
     }, 300);

      // This function is from another post. It gets world coordinates for a 
      // Latlng object.
     function project(latLng) {
       var siny = Math.sin(latLng.lat() * Math.PI / 180);

       // Truncating to 0.9999 effectively limits latitude to 89.189. This is
       // about a third of a tile past the edge of the world tile.
       siny = Math.min(Math.max(siny, -0.9999), 0.9999);

       return new google.maps.Point(
         TILE_SIZE * (0.5 + latLng.lng() / 360),
         TILE_SIZE * (0.5 - Math.log((1 + siny) / (1 - siny)) / (4 * Math.PI)));
     }

      // This function was adapted from code for pixelOffsetForWorldCoordinate
      // or something like that. It will offset the old (incorrect map center)
      // by 0.8 tiles, which is exactly the right amount to match the map 
      // center and marker location in google maps
     function getNewCenter(map, latLng, zoom) {
       var scale = 1 << zoom;

       var worldCoordinate = project(latLng);

       var tileCoordinate = new google.maps.Point(
         worldCoordinate.x * scale / TILE_SIZE,
         worldCoordinate.y * scale / TILE_SIZE
       );

       tileCoordinate.x += 0.8;

       var newWorldCoordinate = {
           x: '',
           y: ''
         },
         tcX = tileCoordinate.x,
         tcY = tileCoordinate.y;

       newWorldCoordinate.x = tcX * TILE_SIZE / scale;
       newWorldCoordinate.y = tcY * TILE_SIZE / scale;

       // convert the new world coordinate to a Latlng object
       var newLatlng = map.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(newWorldCoordinate);

       return newLatlng;
     }
```